# How to sort a multiindex pandas dataframe pivot table by the totals of an agg='sum' at each level of the index

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, pivot-table

Example generated with something like

`df = pd.pivot_table(df, index=['name1','name2','name3'], values='total', aggfunc='sum')`

No logical sort initially

```
name1  name2  name3  total
Bob    Mario  Luigi  5
       John   Dan    16
Dave   Tom    Jim    2
              Joe    6
              Jack   3
       Jill   Frank  6  
              Kevin  7
```

Should become

```
name1  name2  name3  total
Dave   Jill   Kevin  7
              Frank  6  
       Tom    Joe    6
              Jack   3
              Jim    2
Bob    John   Dan    16 
       Mario  Luigi  5
```

Where Dave is on top because his "total of totals" : 24 is higher than Bob's 21. It propogates to each subsequent index as well so Jill's 13 > Tom's 11, etc. Been messing around with groupby(), sort_values(), sort_index() and determined I don't really know what I'm doing.

Answer (score 0):

What you could do is create additional columns and then do a multicolumn sort.
For the additional column, `transform` will return a Series with the index aligned to the df so you can then add it as a new column:

```
from pandas import DataFrame
mydf = DataFrame({"name1":\
["bob","bob","dave","dave","dave","dave","dave"],"name2":\
["mario","john","tom","tom","tom","jill","jill"],"name3":\
["luigi","dan","jim","joe","jack","frank","kevin"],"total":[5,16,2,6,3,6,7]})
mydf["tot1"]=mydf["total"].groupby(mydf["name1"]).transform(sum)
mydf["tot2"]=mydf["total"].groupby(mydf["name2"]).transform(sum)
mydf["tot3"]=mydf["total"].groupby(mydf["name3"]).transform(sum)
mydf.sort_values(by=["tot1","tot2","tot3"],ascending=[False,False,False])
```

Which yields:

```
   name1  name2  name3  total  tot1  tot2  tot3
6  dave   jill  kevin      7    24    13     7
5  dave   jill  frank      6    24    13     6
3  dave    tom    joe      6    24    11     6
4  dave    tom   jack      3    24    11     3
2  dave    tom    jim      2    24    11     2
1   bob   john    dan     16    21    16    16
0   bob  mario  luigi      5    21     5     5
```